# Cassandra CLUSTERING ORDER does not order data properly

Tags: cassandra

I created a table that has timestamps in it but when I try to Cluster Order By the timestamp variable, it is not ordered properly.

To create the table I wrote:

```
CREATE TABLE videos_by_tag ( 
tag text, 
video_id uuid, 
added_date timestamp, 
title text, 
PRIMARY KEY ((tag), added_date, video_id)) 
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (added_date ASC);
```

And the output I got when doing a `SELECT * FROM videos_by_tag` is:

```
 tag       | added_date                      | video_id                             | title
-----------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------
  datastax | 2013-04-16 00:00:00.000000+0000 | 5645f8bd-14bd-11e5-af1a-8638355b8e3a | What is DataStax Enterprise?
  datastax | 2013-10-16 00:00:00.000000+0000 | 4845ed97-14bd-11e5-8a40-8338255b7e33 |              DataStax Studio
 cassandra | 2012-04-03 00:00:00.000000+0000 | 245e8024-14bd-11e5-9743-8238356b7e32 |             Cassandra & SSDs
 cassandra | 2013-03-17 00:00:00.000000+0000 | 3452f7de-14bd-11e5-855e-8738355b7e3a |              Cassandra Intro
 cassandra | 2014-01-29 00:00:00.000000+0000 | 1645ea59-14bd-11e5-a993-8138354b7e31 |            Cassandra History

(5 rows)
```

As you can see the dates are out of order. There is a 2012 year value in the middle of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common misconception in Cassandra. The data is in fact ordered correctly in the sample data you posted.

The `CLUSTERING ORDER` applies to the sort order of the rows within a partition -- NOT across ALL partitions.

Using the example you posted, the clustering column `added_date` is correctly sorted in ascending order for the partition `tag = 'datastax'`:

```
 tag       | added_date                      
-----------+---------------------------------
  datastax | 2013-04-16 00:00:00.000000+0000 
  datastax | 2013-10-16 00:00:00.000000+0000
```

Similarly, `added_date` is sorted in ascending order for `tag = 'cassandra'`:

```
 tag       | added_date                      
-----------+---------------------------------
 cassandra | 2012-04-03 00:00:00.000000+0000
 cassandra | 2013-03-17 00:00:00.000000+0000
 cassandra | 2014-01-29 00:00:00.000000+0000
```

Like I said, the sort order only applies to rows within a partition.

It would be impossible to sort all rows in all partitions because such task does not scale. Imagine if you had billions of partitions in the table across hundreds of nodes. Every time you inserted a new row to any partition, Cassandra has to do a full table scan to sort the data and it just wouldn't make sense to do so. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can fine-tune the display order using the ORDER BY clause. The partition key must be defined in the WHERE clause and the ORDER BY clause defines the clustering column to use for ordering.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM videos_by_tag
WHERE tag = 'datastax' ORDER BY added_date ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! You're ORDER BY query works but shouldn't Cassandra order everything by added_date because of the Clustering Order By clause when the table was created?

Comment: No, Cassandra can only enforce a sort order within a partition.